# AWS Amplify Code Build Error of Adding Isolated Modules For Me Then Failing The Build

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify, aws-codebuild

**Desired Outcome:** To implement testing into the CI/CD pipeline for AWS Amplify by utilising the front-end testing framework of Cypress.

**Problem:** I am failing to build the front-end section on the AWS Amplify Code Build (Backend Builds). It builds without testing and cypress.

**Error:**

```
2023-01-07T10:45:07.106Z [INFO]: info  - Checking validity of types...
2023-01-07T10:45:07.318Z [INFO]: We detected TypeScript in your project and reconfigured your tsconfig.json file for you. Strict-mode is set to false by default.
2023-01-07T10:45:07.318Z [INFO]: The following mandatory changes were made to your tsconfig.json:
                                 - isolatedModules was set to true (requirement for SWC / Babel)
2023-01-07T10:45:12.361Z [WARNING]: Failed to compile.
2023-01-07T10:45:12.364Z [WARNING]: ./amplify/backend/node_modules/@aws-amplify/graphql-transformer-interfaces/src/index.ts:2:10
                                    Type error: Re-exporting a type when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided requires using 'export type'.
                                    [0m [90m 1 | [39m[36mexport[39m [33m*[39m from [32m'./transformer-context'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
                                    [0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 2 | [39m[36mexport[39m { [33mTransformerPluginProvider[39m[33m,[39m [33mTransformerPluginType[39m } from [32m'./transformer-plugin-provider'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m   | [39m         [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m 3 | [39m[36mexport[39m {[0m
                                    [0m [90m 4 | [39m  [33mMutationFieldType[39m[33m,[39m[0m
                                    [0m [90m 5 | [39m  [33mQueryFieldType[39m[33m,[39m[0m
2023-01-07T10:45:12.393Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-01-07T10:45:12.393Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-01-07T10:45:12.393Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-01-07T10:45:12.393Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-01-07T10:45:12.468Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-01-07T10:45:12.468Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
```

**Root Package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper": "^2.3.33",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^3.4.1",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.2",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.45",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.49.0",
    "card-validator": "^8.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express-jwt": "^7.7.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "jarallax": "^1.12.8",
    "jwks-rsa": "^2.1.4",
    "ksuid": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "next-global-css": "^1.3.1",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "0.0.14",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-countup": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.5",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "sharp": "^0.30.7",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.1.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.7.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1135.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "cypress": "^12.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.1.6",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
```

Looking at this [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7959), it looks like a typescript and babel configuration issue. I've set `isolatedModules` to true already in my `tsconfig.json` root file.

**Local `npm run build` error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing `"@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper"` to version: `"^2.3.25"` fixed this issue.